# How do I (properly) inherit classes from EWS such as an Appointment?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Same problem as:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294207/exchange-web-services-argumentexception-using-my-own-contact-class

I am trying to write a derived class from Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment. However, the derived class cannot be saved without throwing what appears to be a serialization error. This happens even if I make no modifications to the derived class.

This works:

```
public void CreateTestAppointment() {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(Exchange) {
            ItemClass = "IPM.Appointment", //Exchange Specific. Dont touch unless you     know what this does. I sure as hell don't.
            Subject = string.Format("{0} Test", "Oliver")
        };
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("okane@cottinghambutler.com");
        appointment.Body = new MessageBody {
            Text = "Meeting invite body text placeholder"
        };

        //Add item to the appropriate categories
        appointment.Categories.Add(string.Format("[C]{0}", "Arbitrary Client Group"));

        // Add calendar properties to the appointment.
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

        appointment.Save(Hc360CallCalendarFolderId, SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
    }
```

But this doesn't:

```
 public void CreateTestAppointment() {
        InheritedAppointment appointment = new InheritedAppointment(Exchange) {
            ItemClass = "IPM.Appointment", //Exchange Specific. Dont touch unless you know what this does. I sure as hell don't.
            Subject = string.Format("{0} Test", "Oliver")
        };
        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("okane@cottinghambutler.com");
        appointment.Body = new MessageBody {
            Text = "Meeting invite body text placeholder"
        };

        //Add item to the appropriate categories
        appointment.Categories.Add(string.Format("[C]{0}", "Arbitrary Client Group"));

        // Add calendar properties to the appointment.
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        appointment.End = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);

        appointment.Save(Hc360CallCalendarFolderId, SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
    }
```

Which is very strange, as I'm not actually doing anything in the derived class.

```
    public class InheritedAppointment : Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment {
    public InheritedAppointment(ExchangeService serivce)
        : base(serivce) {

    }}
```

It looks like this is being seralized to XML, and some value is null, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.  Here's the raw error

> Test Name:    TestMeetingCreation Test
>   FullName: Hc360LibTests.UnitTest1.TestMeetingCreation Test
>   Source:   c:\Users\okane\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HealthCheck360OutlookCallScheduleHelper\Hc360LibTests\UnitTest1.cs
>   : line 15 Test Outcome:   Failed Test Duration:   0:00:00.5728502
>
> Result Message:    Test method
>   Hc360LibTests.UnitTest1.TestMeetingCreation threw exception: 
>   System.ArgumentException: The empty string '' is not a valid local
>   name. Result StackTrace:   at
>   System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String
>   localName, String ns)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlWriter.WriteStartElement(XmlNamespace
>   xmlNamespace, String localName)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.WriteToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter
>   writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CreateRequest`2.WriteElementsToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter
>   writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WriteBodyToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter
>   writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.WriteToXml(EwsServiceXmlWriter
>   writer)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.EmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest&
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1
>   items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition,
>   Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>
>   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId
>   parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1
>   sendInvitationsMode)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment.Save(FolderId
>   destinationFolderId, SendInvitationsMode sendInvitationsMode)    at
>   HealthCheck360ExchangeLib.CallSlotRepository.CreateTestAppointment()
>   in c:\Users\okane\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HealthCheck360OutlookCallScheduleHelper\HealthCheck360ExchangeLib\CallSlotRepository.cs:line
>   70    at Hc360LibTests.UnitTest1.TestMeetingCreation() in
>   c:\Users\okane\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HealthCheck360OutlookCallScheduleHelper\Hc360LibTests\UnitTest1.cs:line
>   17

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to save an inherited item.

If you look deep enough in the code for the EWS Managed API you will find that the serialization determines the element names in the XML from either the ServiceObjectDefinitionAttribute or from the method ServiceObject.GetXmlElementNameOverride.  The [Appointment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) inherits from Item which in turn inherits from ServiceObject.  The Appointment class also has the ServiceObjectDefinitionAttribute and is serialized with the XML element name "CalendarItem".

So, to use a class inherited from Appointment you need to either use the ServiceObjectDefintionAttribute on your class or you have to override GetXmlElementNameOverride.  Unfortunately ServiceObjectDefintionAttribute and GetXmlElementNameOverride are internal so there is no way to do this.

The question is why do you want to use an inherited class?  Did you expect Exchange to be able to save the properties on your class?  In that case you might want to take a look at  [ExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633691%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

If you want to expose the extended properties as real properties on your own class you can do it by delegating to an Appointment object.  It is not perfect but it is an option:

```
public class ExtendedAppointment
{
    Appointment _appointment;

    public ExtendedAppointment(Appointment appointment)
    {
        _appointment = appointment;
    }

    public Appointment Appointment { get { return _appointment; } }

    public object SomeExtendedProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _appointment.ExtendedProperties[0].Value;
        }

        set
        {
            _appointment.ExtendedProperties[0].Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the EWS open source? I didn't realize I could look deeper than the stack trace.

Comment: Since I cannot use the ServiceObjectDefintionAttribute attribute, I shall have to write my own class.  My goal was to write a class which used ExtendedProperties and present them as Properties on my inherited class.  In other words, my derived class could have something such as a public string called ClientGroupName, that the underlying Appointment could take care of the implementation details.  It's much cleaner than using Extended Properties in the repository itself.  Or at least, I feel it's the wrong place to place the code.

Comment: EWS is not open source.  I used ILSpy to view the code.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Props for ILSpy, this is an awesome tool.  

I had actually just implemented a delegate object (I previously used the self-described term "wrapper", that's for that correction) as a work around. It's inelegant, but I can't think of a better way.  Many thanks for your assistance! I'll bump up this answer when I gain enough Rep to do so.

Comment: Just as an update, EWS Managed API is now open sourced - https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api